# High pitched whine coming from the GPU/PSU?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, gpu

This problem only happened today, and it has been getting really annoying.

```
SPECS:
Intel Core i3-3210 @ 3.2GHz
4GB x 2 RAM
AMD Radeon R7 200 Series
```

Now, Whenever I play games at a supposedly uncapped FPS, My GPU/PSU (I think that GPU is more likely) emits a high pitched noise, it's really loud, I can hear it from 2 metres away.

Is it just a coil whine? This rig is only around 8 months old, a custom build, I have also noticed a few other problems popping up from my computer lately such as bluescreening more often `(STOP: PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA)` And it first happened when I was playing Moonbase Alpha but it seemed like a capped FPS for me (It was running at around 20 or 15 FPS for a powerful GPU), But what I have REALLY NOTICED is that these problems seemed to ONLY HAPPEN in summer. It only happened when Summer started.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to pull the computer's cover and isolate where the noise is coming from, that will let you make a better determination as to where to go next.  It could be something as simple as a throttled fan at full throttle making more noise than you are used to. Keep an eye on system temperatures and make sure they stay in the norm.  If the noise isn't fan related, it might be a possibly faulty component, but that is hard to judge.  Best to research the part making the noise and comparing notes with other owners..

Start simple and work backwards from there.  And make sure it isn't a playing card stuck in the spokes of the fan (that was a joke for the old guys like me)..

Comment: Temperatures are normal..

Comment: What are they and how are you measuring them?  Also, did you measure them under full load?  Your BSOD might be related to heat as well.  Are your heatsinks, vents and fans all clear of debris and anything that might keep air from flowing?  I've had more than a few users stuff computers in a tight space with no airflow and wonder why they have heat related issues.  Also, pet hair and dust can be huge as well.

Comment: I measured them when there was less to no load at all. It has been getting a little bit hot here, That's why i'm going to agree that it's the heat, and not my doing.